# Authorize attribute with policy requirement throwing: The following authentication scheme was not accepted

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this simple setup for policy requirement. I am assuming that this should return 401 but instead it is throwing an exception

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.ConfigureAuthorization(options =>
        {
            var policyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();                
            policyBuilder.AddRequirements(new MyPolicyRequirement());
            options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policyBuilder.Build());
        });
        services.AddMvc();            
    }

    // Configure is called after ConfigureServices is called.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //app.UseErrorPage();            
        app.UseStaticFiles();            
        app.UseMvc();           
    }
}
```

**MyPolicyRequirement.cs**

```
public class MyPolicyRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<MyPolicyRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, MyPolicyRequirement requirement)
    {            
        if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "yes"))
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);                 
    }
}
```

**ValuesController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }        
}
```

The process flow for this as I understand it is that you register an Authorization policy then you use it with the Authorize attribute then this will be checked prior of executing the method on the controller however this is not happening and instead I am getting this exception

**Exception**

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The following authentication scheme was not accepted: 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<ChallengeAsync>d__10.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ChallengeResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__53.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__41.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.<InvokeActionAsync>d__7.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.<RouteAsync>d__6.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.InnerAttributeRoute.<RouteAsync>d__10.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__9.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<<Start>b__0>d.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.RuntimeHttpApplication.<ProcessRequestAsyncImpl>d__13.MoveNext() 
--- exception rethrown --- 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.RuntimeHttpApplication.<ProcessRequestAsyncImpl>d__13.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.HttpApplicationBase.<InvokeProcessRequestAsyncImpl>d__9.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have is a bunch of authorization pieces, but no authentication middlware, so the system doesn't know what it's supposed to do when authorization fails.

The return status code would depend on the authentication middleware you choose. If you chose bearer tokens then you would get a 401 back, assuming the middleware is correct. If you chose cookie auth you'd get a 302 back, because that's aimed at browsers and is attempting to redirect to your login page.

For example, if, in your Configure() you add

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie";
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Unauthorized/");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/");
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
});
```

You'd probably see a redirect to /Account/Unauthorized when your authentication happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

How can I write a custom authentication provider? what do I need to inherit from?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the samples I have at https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorization-Samples. The MultipleAuthTypes solution has a sample, simple, authentication middleware

Comment: You can also see the full cookie middleware at https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs